# Bash Script - Find "ERROR" and output to file

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I'm writing my first bash script and could use some help / advice. I cannot test the script at the moment - just want to know if I have it setup correctly.

I have a file $A_HOME/bin/nohup.out and I'm searching for the term "ERROR".  I need it to output results to a file, such as output_error.csv or output_error.txt.

Based on what I've read, this is the script I've come up with

```
find "$A_HOME"/bin/nohup.out -exec grep "ERROR" {} /; -print >> output_error.csv
```

or

```
grep -r ERROR "$A_HOME"/bin/nohup.out >> output_error.csv
```

Can anyone help me out? I think I'm supposed to use find, but I've read it's not necessary in situations like this.

Much appreciated.

Comment: wait, do you or do you not know where "nohup.out" is? Why are you using `find` instead of `grep ERROR "$A_HOME"/bin/nohup.out > output_error.txt`

Comment: I do. Sorry, about that, I mistakingly left out the full path - this is my first script. I was told to use find - is it not necessary?

Comment: If you know the full path then find is not necessary as you already know how to find it and where it is.

Comment: Your second command should work, although `-r` is meaningless if you're looking at a single file.